# Rock, paper or scissors game - doesn't return expression of who wins, etc

Tags: javascript

I made a basic "Rock, paper or scissors" game. I have a few doubts/problems about this project.

On my browser the message of who wins isn't displayed. Such as "Computer wins". What I get is the following:

> Computer: Paper
>
> You: rock

And my code is:

```
let userChoice = prompt("Do you choose Rock, Paper or Scissors?");
let computerChoice = Math.random();
if (computerChoice < 0.34) {
computerChoice = "Rock";
} else if(computerChoice <= 0.67) {
computerChoice = "Paper";
} else {
computerChoice = "Scissors";
} 

let compare = function(choice1, choice2) {
if (choice1 === choice2) {
    document.getElementById('printwo').innerHTML =  'The result is a    tie!';
 }
 else if (choice1 === "Rock"){
     if (choice2 ==="Scissors") {
          document.getElementById('printwo').innerHTML =  'Rock wins';
         }

     else {
          document.getElementById('printwo').innerHTML =  'Paper wins';
         }
     }
     else if (choice1 === 'Paper') {
     if (choice2 === 'Rock') {
          document.getElementById('printwo').innerHTML =  'Paper wins';
         }
     else {
          document.getElementById('printwo').innerHTML =  'Scissors wins';
         }

     }
     else if (choice1 === 'Scissors') {
         if (choice2 ==='Rock') {
              document.getElementById('printwo').innerHTML =  'Rock wins';
             }
         else  {
             document.getElementById('printwo').innerHTML = 'Scissors wins';
             }
         }

};

 document.getElementById("print").innerHTML = "Computer: " + computerChoice + "</br>" + "You: " + userChoice;
 compare(userChoice, computerChoice);
```

I also wanted to add an `else statement` to give the message "Please insert a valid response" in case the user doesn't choose any of the 3 options. But where should I place it inside the function? I tried putting it at the end but then it always displayed the message, no matter what I wrote.

Instead of so many `else if` statements, why can't I write this game using a function which contains many lines of code such as this one:

```
else if(userChoice === 'Paper' && computerChoice === 'Paper') {
return ('It\'s a tie!'); }
```

Last but not least, why doesn't it work to use `return` (instead of `document.getElementById()`) inside the function and then call the function inside of `document.getElementById()`

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I also wanted to add an else statement to give the message "Please insert a valid response" in case the user doesn't choose any of the 3 options. But where should I place it inside the function? I tried putting it at the end but then it always displayed the message, no matter what I wrote.

This doesn't belong in the `compare` function.
It will be best when you get the user input.
You might want to repeatedly ask the user until you get a valid input, for example:

```
const choices = ['Rock', 'Paper', 'Scissors'];
var userChoice;
while (true) {
  prompt("Do you choose Rock, Paper or Scissors?");
  if (choices.indexOf(userChoice) != -1) break;
  console.log('Invalid choice!');
}
```

By the way, defining the `choices` also lets you simplify the way you set the computer's choice:

```
let computerChoice = choices[Math.floor(Math.random() * choices.length)];
```

> Instead of so many else if statements, why can't I write this game using a function which contains many lines of code such as this one:
>   `else if(userChoice === 'Paper' && computerChoice === 'Paper') {
>   return ('It\'s a tie!'); }`

You don't actually have that exact line, thanks to the `choice1 === choice2` condition.
In any case, there's nothing fundamentally wrong with having all those if-else-ifs.
You could use a different approach, for example an object oriented one,
where each object would know what other choice beats it and what doesn't,
but it's not so obvious that such approach would be significantly better.

> Last but not least, why doesn't it work to use `return` (instead of `document.getElementById()`) inside the function and then call the function inside of `document.getElementById()`

Indeed, it would be better to remove all the repetitive `document.getElementById('printwo').innerHTML =` from inside the `compare` function.
You could write like this instead:

```
let compare = function(choice1, choice2) {
  if (choice1 === choice2) {
    return 'The result is a    tie!';
  } else if (choice1 === "Rock") {
    if (choice2 === "Scissors") {
      return 'Rock wins';
    } else {
      return 'Paper wins';
    }
  } else if (choice1 === 'Paper') {
    if (choice2 === 'Rock') {
      return 'Paper wins';
    } else {
      return 'Scissors wins';
    }
  } else {
    if (choice2 === 'Rock') {
      return 'Rock wins';
    } else  {
      return 'Scissors wins';
    }
  }
};

document.getElementById('printwo').innerHTML = compare(userChoice, computerChoice);
```

A more compact writing style is possible with using the ternary operator `?:`:

```
  if (choice1 === choice2) {
    return 'The result is a    tie!';
  } else if (choice1 === "Rock") {
    return choice2 === "Scissors" ? 'Rock wins' : 'Paper wins';
  } else if (choice1 === 'Paper') {
    return choice2 === "Rock" ? 'Paper wins' : 'Scissors wins';
  } else {
    return choice2 === "Rock" ? 'Rock wins' : 'Scissors wins';
  }
```

Here's an alternative data-driven approach:

```
const rps = {
  rock: {
    paper: 'Paper wins',
    scissors: 'Rock wins'
  },
  paper: {
    rock: 'Paper wins',
    scissors: 'Scissors wins'
  },
  scissors: {
    rock: 'Rock wins',
    paper: 'Scissors wins'
  }
};

let compare = function(choice1, choice2) {
  if (choice1 === choice2) {
    return 'The result is a tie!';
  }
  return rps[choice1.toLowerCase()][choice2.toLowerCase()];
};
```

Comment: thank you so much for your answer but I didn't quite understand whether you were telling me I could do the statement I mentioned with the "&&" or not.

Comment: @SpencerHastings I don't see a place in this code where a `&&` would be useful. None of the nested if-else can be merged with their enclosing conditions.

Comment: @SpencerHastings Do you mean `else if(userChoice === 'Paper' && computerChoice === 'Paper')`? It’s actually not clear, why you would want to write it that way. You are already checking `if (choice1 === choice2)`.

Comment: No, I am talking about a completely different code. Such as : `else if(userChoice === 'Paper' && computerChoice ==='Scissors') {return 'Computer wines!';}` and `else if (userChoice === 'Scissors' && computerChoice === 'Scissors') {return 'It is a tie';}` ... And the same thing for the remaining possibilities. @Xufox @janos

Comment: @SpencerHastings as I wrote earlier, no, I don't see an opportunity here to simplify the code using `&&`, anywhere.

Comment: @SpencerHastings I added to my answer a data-driven approach that reduces greatly the conditional statements